# Issues in initial setup for django project

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django from the official documentation and while going through the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/, I am stuck at creating a project part.

When I run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` I am getting following error

```
C:\Python34>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]
Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Raise on exception
  --no-color            Don't colorize the command output.
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Available subcommands:
[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqldropindexes
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
```

Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured

```
error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured
    . You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

I am using Python 3.4.1 and django 1.7. I don't have any other Django version installed and this is the first project I am creating.

Comment: Have you checked the troubleshooting guide https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin-py? It looks like you don't have django-admin.py on your system path

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went through the troubleshooting guide and all i had to do was
C:\Python34\Scripts>python django-admin.py startproject mysite
Though i must say that i didnt use virtualenv to install django. But prepending python did the trick.

Comment: Cool i'll put a bit more info in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you follow the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/troubleshooting/) because it looks like you don't have django-admin.py on your system path correctly. From the docs:

> django-admin.py should be on your system path if you installed Django
> via python setup.py. If it’s not on your path, you can find it in
> site-packages/django/bin, where site-packages is a directory within
> your Python installation. Consider symlinking to django-admin.py from
> some place on your path, such as /usr/local/bin.

You should also use a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for each of your projects to allow isolation of dependencies per project and easier management of them. [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a useful tool for creating and managing your virtualenvs.

Answer (score 25):

You can just run `django-admin startproject mysite`（Note: not `django-admin.py`）, because if you install django by pip, a executable program named 'django-admin.exe' will be added to  *'C:\Python34\Scripts*', which is already in your environment variable 'PATH' normally(if not, add it to PATH).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while installing **Django 2.0.5**. This can be resolved using **Virtual Environments**.

---

**Environment details:**

- Python version: 3.6
- OS: Ubuntu 18.xx.x

---

**Steps:**

1. Install Virtual Environment 
       `pip install virtualenv`
2. Create a Virtual work-space('VEnv') 
       `virtualenv --python=python3 VEnv`
3. Activate the Virtual Environment:
       `cd VEnv/ 
       source bin/activate`
4. Install Django(Version - 2.0.5) 
       `pip install django==2.0.5`
5. Create Project (Project Name: HelloDot)
       `django-admin startproject HelloDot`
6. Run the server as below and then access it from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" 
       `cd HelloDot/ 
       python manage.py runserver 8000`

---

For more details, take a look at this: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-django-on-ubuntu/