# I have "Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS" warnings

Tags: django, django-management-command

I'm attempting to extend from the `BaseCommand` class in Django. However, on running `$ python manage.py runserver` I'm receiving the following error:

`Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS`

My `settings.py`:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "aksalist",
]
```

When I run `test_et.py`, this error occurs.

In `test_et.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from aksalist.models import *

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Get single products from cs-cart'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        pass

bolge = Bolgeler.objects.all()
personel = Aksalist.objects.all()[0]

gunler = ("2018-08-28", "2018-08-29", "2018-08-30")
vardiyalar = ("07:30 - 15:30", "15:30 - 23:30","23:30 - 07:30")

for i in gunler:
    for y in vardiyalar:
        for z in bolge:
           obj = VardiyalarRMS.objects.create(gun=i, bolge=z, vardiya_donemi=y)
    print(obj)
exit()
```

my errors

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/17446/Desktop/aksamer/aksalist/management/commands/test_et.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aksalist.models import *
  File "C:\Users\17446\Desktop\aksamer\aksalist\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Birim(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\17446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\17446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\17446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\17446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\17446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues in initial setup for django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664654/issues-in-initial-setup-for-django-project)

Comment: How are you running `test_py`?

Comment: which error are you talking about?

Comment: Would it be ok to include the full error trace for the error you're receiving please...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your INSTALLED_APPS order is not quite correct in your `settings.py` file. Please try the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'suit',
    'aksalist'
]
```

Unless you're calling `test.py` directly, in which case you will need to be inside you Django `shell` environment (`$ python manage.py shell`) to be able to work with `Models`

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be inside the `handle` method. As it is, it's at module level, so is executed when the script is imported, before the settings have been properly activated.

The fact that you had to put a `pass` in that handle method should have given you a clue that somethng was wrong. Put the rest of the code there instead.